# How were the probabilities of recession over the next four quarters calculated in this table?

Tags: probability, economics

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-02-08/goldman-sachs-says-defy-mr-market-as-recession-risk-still-low

[image]

> The probability of a slump in the U.S. is just 18 percent and 23
>   percent over the two timeframes respectively, while the euro-area
>   threat is greater at 24 percent and 38 percent, according to Goldman
>   Sachs.

Article was published on 8Feb2016.

Comment: Do you have access to the original source of the table?

Comment: Unfortunately, what I have is from the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to compute this. Refer to [The Yield Curve as a Leading Indicator](https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/capital_markets/ycfaq.html), [An Economic Characterization of Business Cycle Dynamics with Factor Structure and Regime Switching](http://faculty.ucr.edu/~chauvet/ier.pdf), and [Smoothed U.S. Recession Probabilities](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/RECPROUSM156N). These are used in academic and by practitioners alike.